# Memory issues debugging an app : c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, out-of-memory

I have an app which is basically exporting DB data to Excel. It was working fine (given the fact that it is playing around with 1 million rows). While debugging the app, I was checking the task manager for memory consumption and the vshost32 exe was using around 4 GB. From some time (yesterday) when I tried to run the same app (with loads of data as before) I ran out of memory. I tried that again and every time when the app tries to use more than a 1.4 GB, it ends up with an exception. I haven't changed any code so I am really wondering where this strange behavior comes from?

I am using 32 bit Visual Studio 2012 on quad core processor with 8 GB of ram and a virtual Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: What method are you using to write excel file; also have you considered switching app to x64 ? Btw. recommended reading - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Comment: It is a library called epplus, which as I stated was doing fine a few days ago with 32 bit compilation..

Comment: actually I lied to you .. in the Project Properties / Build the platform target was ANY CPU, and the prefer 32 bit was ticked. I changed that to 64 bit and now it works as before .. so thanks I will accept your comment as answer :)